# GRUB changes are not applied

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, boot-loader

I am trying to hide the GRUB menu on Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon.

I edited the grub file using and entering my admin password twice

```
gedit admin:///etc/default/grub
```

Then I edited my grub file to look like this:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

After the changes, I updated GRUB with

```
sudo update-grub
```

When I restart the PC, I still get the GRUB menu with a 30 second timer.
Did I miss some entries or are there also other files I need to edit?

Comment: try to remove GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT and GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET and don't forget info grub.

Comment: Thanks! Iĺl try that. What exactly do you mean by info grub? Is that a terminal command to look at the settings? (Sorry, absolute noob here)

Comment: I suppose ctac_'s reference to "info grub" is about the Texinfo documentation you can invoke with `info grub`. (Also [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)). Compared to their `info` counterparts, man pages for GNU software (see e.g. `man -k grub`) are often quite terse.

Comment: @ctac_ thanks for the suggestions! I tried that but nothing changed :/

Comment: @GAD3R This worked! Thanks a lot! If you post as an answer, I can accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0` in your `/etc/default/grub` then run `update-grub`.

```
info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration' | less  -p 'GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT'
```

> ```
> 'GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT'
>
> If this option is set, it overrides the default recordfail setting.
>  A setting of -1 causes GRUB to wait for user input indefinitely.
>  However, a false positive in the recordfail mechanism may occur if
>  power is lost during boot before boot success is recorded in
>  userspace.  The default setting is 30, which causes GRUB to wait
>  for user input for thirty seconds before continuing.  This default
>  allows interactive users the opportunity to switch to a different,
>  working kernel, while avoiding a false positive causing the boot to
>  block indefinitely on headless and appliance systems where access
>  to a console is restricted or limited.
> ```